# count first value, second value or both

Tags: mysql

I need to do a count, if the first or the second value is true, it should be one, and if both are correct, the value should be two:

```
 select count(*) from table1 where (cond1 or cond2)
```

it should be something like this, but I cant get it.

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Put here the table columns names. Also write, what column you are counting and what column should be true. Also, you want to count all rows if the two first lines has one true value?

Comment: why do you need to do a count() if you know it should be 1 or 2?

Comment: it could be 0 if both are false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(cond1) + SUM(cond2) FROM table1 WHERE cond1 OR cond2
```